# Error while trying to access a redux state inside of async function in next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

```
"use client"
import SearchResults from "./searchResults";
import axios from "axios";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const getRecipe = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=cake&app_id=API_ID&app_key=API_KEY`
  );
  const data = await response.data;

  return data;
};

const SearchRecipe = async () => {
  const recipes = await getRecipe();
  const searchTerm = useSelector((state) => state.recipe.value.searchTerm);
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchRecipe;
```

const searchTerm = useSelector((state) => state.recipe.value.searchTerm);  here i am trying to access the searchTerm state from the slice i created using redux toolkit but when i run this component Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')  this error is showing it worked just fine in another components.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use async components for client side code. Async components are made for server side components.

Also, in your case, you should use `useEffect` for fetching data.